# horizontial scrollbar disappear when sorting header column, is it a bug?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Demo is found at `link removed` and using jqgrid version 4.9.2

There you'll see horizontal scrollbar is doing fine.

Step to reproduce the issues.

1) resize Model column (make it wider)

2) sort Year column

There, you see horizontal scrollbar simply disappearred and the grid spreadsheet got expanded wider instead.

Oleg - Is that a jqgrid bug?  Or me using jqgrid script incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems me the bug in default behavior of auto-resizing in case of using `autoResizing: { compact: true }` property for some columns. Nevetherless I want to test many different scenarios before fixing the bug in GitHub code. The problem is the existence of many options, which can be important for resizing the column, for example `autowidth`, `shrinkToFit` options, the case when one don't specify any `width` parameter of jqGrid or one do specify the `width` with some specific value (like you do) or one specify `width: "auto"` or `width: "100%"` and so on.

As a workaround I would recommend you to specify explicitly `adjustGridWidth` property of `autoResizing` parameter of jqGrid:

```js
autoResizing: { adjustGridWidth: false }
```

It will prevent adjustment of the width of the grid on resizing of the column.

Comment: Oleg: - I commented out `autowidth`, `shrinkToFit` and `forceFit`.  The only width option setting I used is the `width: 1022` for jqgrid table.   Tried it again and the bug still exists.   As per your recommendation, I replaced `compact: true` with `adjustGridWidth` in `autoResizing` and the bug goes away.  Now we know what it is.  Thanks.

Comment: @fletchsod: You are welcome! The bug exist in case of using `autoResizing: { compact: true }` property for some columns. In your case commenting of `autowidth`, `shrinkToFit` and `forceFit` will not help. I mention the parameters because bug fixing existing in your case can produce some new bug in case of using other combination of the options. I fixed in the past some bugs and made new bugs with other options. I wrote it because I still didn't fixed the bug on GitHub and just suggested you the above workaround.